# Maven isn't installing correctly

Tags: maven, installation, maven-3, system-variable

I am trying to install maven v3.5.4 onto my computer and whenever I try the 'mvn -version' command, I get

> 'mvn' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

I have looked up multiple tutorials on how to do this, and they are giving nearly the same information. Add system variables M2 and M2_HOME, then append a directory to the Path system variable. I have the System Variables configured to the following:

**M2:**

- Name: M2
- Value: C:\Program Files\Apache\maven\bin

**M2_HOME:**

- Name: M2_HOME
- Value: C:\Program Files\Apache\maven

**MAVEN_HOME:**

- Name: MAVEN_HOME
- Value: C:\Program Files\Apache\maven

**Path:**

- Name: Path
- Value: %M2_HOME%\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\bin

I have seen people saying that there should be a .exe or .bat file inside the bin directory. I do not have any of these. I only have 4 files inside this folder. [image: Maven bin directory]

This could perhaps be the issue. The path to my Maven directory is: [image: Maven Folder Path]
I have the following maven related system variables:

[image: System Variables]

And my Path variable is:

[image: Path Variable]

I'm not sure how to fix this issue so if anyone knows, please let me know.

Comment: `%M2_HOME%\bin %JAVA_HOME%\bin` ?? is it by mistake or missing `;`

Comment: By mistake, meant to put a ; I'll fix that

Comment: have you added your `JAVA_HOME` variable linked to your jdk directory? Also you should setup `MAVEN_HOME` with value `C:\Program Files\Apache\maven` to avoid troubles.

Comment: Yes, JAVA_HOME is added as a System Variable. I tried adding MAVEN_HOME and testing the mvn command still gives the error.

Comment: Can you navigate into your maven/bin folder and type "mvn --version"?

Comment: @Plasma There is no .exe or .bat file in my '/bin' folder. I am using version 3.5.4 like you. The bin folder looks fine. I'm confident that a fresh installation of Maven will fix your problem. If this doesn't work either, try restarting your computer too.

Comment: @TA I tried navigating there and I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: @P.Soutzikevich I restarted my computer after a fresh installation and it still doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: in all of this, are you closing the command line after you do some changes to the PATH? The new changes for system variables  are not beeing reflected to the console until you restart it.

Answer (score 2):

Add a variable `MAVEN_HOME` like:

Name: `MAVEN_HOME`

Value: `C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin`

In your case, the `M2_HOME` path is not correct. Hence It must not be working. Try to give the correct path to the `bin folder`.

Comment: I added the variable MAVEN_HOME however I added it as C:\Program Files\Apache\maven and not the bin directory. I added the bin directory and it still does not seem to be working. Also, I have maven installed to C:\Program Files\Apache\maven not C:\Program files\apache-maven-3.3.9

Comment: @Plasma path name is not issue. It was just for an example. maven is also correct however you need to provide path till bin and It must work.

Comment: @Plasma Secondly What is the error you are getting after adding path till bin??

Comment: @Plasma Are you doing this in system variable or user variable?

Comment: I adding this as a system variable and not a user variable. Also, the error I'm getting is in the question.

Comment: @Plasma add this in user variable and let me know then.

Comment: I did. And in the reply, I said I did.

Comment: @Plasma paste the url of screenshoot of your user variable path. Let me check where things are going wrong.

Comment: I put the screenshot into the question.

Comment: @Plasma screenshot of your user variable settings.

Comment: I don't use user variables, I'm using System Variables for this and, I put screenshots of those in the question.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to download maven from [here](https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi?Preferred=ftp%3A%2F%2Fapache.cs.utah.edu%2Fapache.org%2F), preferably the latest version and install it.

Then, you have to set the **Path** variable for Maven.

Go to *Start* and search for *'Edit the system environment variables'*.
Choose the *environment variables* option and like you do in the example you provided, leave **M2_HOME** as you have it, delete **M2** and change the one in your path to: **%M2_HOME%\bin\;**

Also, please make sure that you are editing the **system environment variables**.

As I it says on the download page of the version you are trying to install: ***"Maven 3.3+ require JDK 1.7 or above to execute"***. So make sure you have the right version of java.

If this does not work, then I don't think someone on Stack-Overflow can help.

Comment: I have done this and it doesn't seem to be working. And yes I am editting System environment variables and not User variables.

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling maven? If you are using Windows, then use this [link](http://www-eu.apache.org/dist/maven/maven-3/3.5.4/binaries/apache-maven-3.5.4-bin.zip). It's the current stable version.

Comment: @Plasma I have updated my answer. The problem might be the version of Java you are using. You need java 7 or later

Comment: I'm using Java 8 and I tried uninstalling and reinstalling maven using your link and I am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

### Install Java

1. Download `Java SE Development Kit` from Oracle's website and install it
2. Browse via windows search to  `Environment Variables`
3. Press `New...` in System variables list
4. Insert `JAVA_HOME` to Variable name
5. Insert its path to Variable value (e.g: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102`)
6. Press `Edit` to Path and then press New
7. Insert `%JAVA_HOME%\bin`
8. Open cmd and type `java -version` to check if it is ok

### Install Maven

1. Download `Maven Binary zip archive` from Apaches's website
2. Unzip the folder and move it to `C:\Program Files`
3. Browse via windows search to  `Environment Variables`
4. Press `New...` in System variables list
5. Insert `MAVEN_HOME` to Variable name
6. Insert its path to Variable value (e.g: `C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.6.2`)
7. Press `Edit` to Path and then press New
8. Insert `%MAVEN_HOME%\bin`
9. Open cmd and type `mvn -version` to check if it is ok